# Django equivalent of SELECT * GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm having troubles using `.annotate()` and `.aggregate()` in Django ORM.

My table structure:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id    group_id               date_time            |
| ================================================= |
| 1        1             2020-01-25 19:51:46.603859 |
| 2        2             2020-01-24 18:40:24.301419 |
| 3        1             2020-01-25 20:14:11.123860 |
| 4        2             2020-01-25 05:20:21.507901 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

//Edited

I have the following MySQL Query:

```sql
SELECT m.*
FROM my_table m 
  JOIN (
   SELECT group_id, max(date_time) as max_date
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY group_id
  ) as s on m.group_id=s.group_id and m.date_time=s.max_date
```

Which returns:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id    group_id               date_time            |
| ================================================= |
| 3        1             2020-01-25 19:51:46.603859 |
| 4        2             2020-01-24 18:40:24.301419 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

And I'm trying to convert it to Django ORM so I can have a full QuerySet of objects. Until now I have been using this code:

```py
unique_qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id__lte=50).values_list('group_id', flat=True).distinct()
unique_obj = []
for qs in unique_qs: 
    unique_obj.append(MyModel.objects.filter(group_id = qs).latest('date_time'))
```

But it's really inefficient and time consuming. Could you give me some lead on how to achieve it?

Comment: Your original query is incorrect. It is incompatible with newer MySQL versions as you are grouping by with column list that do not contain all the non-aggregate columns in your select (id). Not sure what you are out after with the query. If your intent is just get max times for each group, do not use *, but use `select group_id, max(date_time)`. The query runs in old MySQL versions and in newer ones with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` turned off. After you fix the query, it's easier to do the Django ORM.

Comment: @slaakso What version are you using? I'm using 10.4.11-MariaDB and it works just about fine.


By words what I'm trying to achieve: I need to select a full row with max date_time for each group_id

Comment: MariaDB does not have by default the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode on (even though it IMHO should have). MySQL already added this as default in 5.7.5. Probably the most common source of errors in MySQL/MariaDB is the incorrect use of `GROUP BY`. The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` goes long way of fixing this as users will be notified of the errors they might have. What is it that you are trying to achieve withe the query? Note that MariaDB returns ID 1 even though it has nothing to do with the max(date_time), it just picks a random one by default. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hGiaVxWKbAc7QHX8NMN5Dy/0

Comment: Gotcha, indeed I didn't have the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option enabled. Now it does give error. So what are my options to solve this problem? Basically what I need is to select latest record for each group.

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hGiaVxWKbAc7QHX8NMN5Dy/1

Comment: @slaakso Thanks for pointing out that problem. I edited the question to support newer MySQL versions. Now hopefully I will be able to convert it to Djangos ORM with some help :-)

Answer (score 1):

first import Max function as you can see below:

```
from django.db.models import Max
```

and then, this is what you need :

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id__lte=50).values('group_id').order_by('group_id').annotate(date_time_max=Max('date_time'))
```

Comment: I think I somehow managed to write that query but It does not do what I need. I need to get full object instances, this returns only the group_id along with date_time_max